# hardcode byte array in C

Tags: c, arrays, syntax

I'm debugging a network application.

I have to simulate some of the data exchanged in order for the application to work. In C++ you can do something like

```
char* myArray = { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22 };
```

However, I can't seem to find a C equivalent for this syntax.

Basically I just want to fill an array with hard coded values.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can do the same thing in C, but you should declare it of type `char[]`, not `char*`, so that you can get its size with the `sizeof` operator:

```
char myArray[] = { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22 };
size_t myArraySize = sizeof(myArray);  // myArraySize = 3
```

Comment: Note that you should use the "char foo[]" syntax in C++ as well

Answer (score 9):

Just for the sake of completeness, with C99 you can also use compound literals:

```
    char *myArray = (char []) {0x00, 0x11, 0x22 };
```

If source code compatibility to C++ is a requirement, you better don't use this construct, because it is - afaik - not part of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 6):

Try with:

```
char myArray[] = { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22 };
```

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't

```
char myArray[] = {0x00, 0x01,0x02};
```

work?

Answer (score 2):

- [Array Initialization](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/initialization.html)
- [Array Initialization](http://c-faq.com/%7Escs/cclass/notes/sx4aa.html)

  char myArray[] = {0x00, 0x11, 0x22};