# Putting Asian and other characters in Visual Studio source code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, encryption, utf-8, aes

I have encrypted a lot of text that resulted in this:

```
const char* encrypted[] = {
"ꖟ럵꼹ᐦෑ䵖","ꗹモ拧ᔞ诞凲ḏ","᜷瞗긚⧿숯塚","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋","掂䉧딻䠕᭖嬽핹ճ","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋","ㄿ爛泰먅轭➊㻎⌧","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋",
"욊蚘坸ꭤ䱤㇔鸽","욊蚘坸ꭤ䱤㇔鸽","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋","䀴♃�ﾊ狥䖢","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋","輶䖙挿斃ぁ忋"
}
```

Problem is, Visual Studio 2013 is giving all sorts of error regarding it. I have changed the encoding to a UTF-8 without BOM, otherwise the compiler crashes right away if I attempt to compile it. It's giving all sorts of errors with the text such as: '0x80': this character is not allowed in an identifier. I tried adding in u8 before the text, to make it UTF-8 for example : `u8"ꖟ럵꼹ᐦෑ䵖"` only to be given the error: u8 identifier not found

Is there a way to successfully load encrypted text into your source code?

Comment: Use `wchar_t` or make each character an escape sequence.

Comment: The output of encryption is not a valid string so you shouldn't store it as a char array. If you must make it into a valid string you need to encode it. Base64 encoding is the standard choice for most applications.

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering why decrypting it did not work.

Comment: Guys, either indicate why this is a question or indicate a dupe. Don't just downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that AES produces output that isn't distinguishable from random. Basically that means that any byte may contain any value. Not all byte values are however valid character encodings. Basically you are asking the system to convert binary back to characters, while the binary never was constructed from characters in the first place.

What happens is that unrecognized byte encodings are silently removed. The same thing may happen with *unprintable* characters such as characters below Unicode code point 0x20 (32). So in the end decoding it to string and encoding it back to bytes will lead to data loss. This data loss of course happens randomly as well; for shorter ciphertext you may be lucky and have no data loss at all.

Now **if** you need a string at all then the answer is to use an encoding that encodes binary into string and back again without loss. For a relatively efficient encoding (4 characters for each 3 bytes) most developers go for base64. If you just want to display some smaller values then hexadecimals will have the advantage of being easier to read by human eyes (at 2 characters for each byte). For test code for ciphertext, keys and IV's in code I personally always prefer hexadecimals as it is easy to see/calculate the size.

In languages such as C/C++ you can also encode everything in a `unsigned char*` using `\xXX`. I would warn against such practices as it coaxes you into using string functions, such as `strlen`. This is of course a problem if null terminated strings are used. Try and keep a clear distinction between characters and bytes at all times, even if the language doesn't. A better alternative is to use [`char[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/883659/589259) (and `sizeof` instead of `strlen`).